# Using .Net Core with OpenGL on LInux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, opengl

Can I use OpenGL in .Net Core on Linux. I asking, because I encountered a few problems...

If not, which library can I use?

Comment: OpenGL (named "Open Graphics Library") is a library so, uh, yes you have to use a library? First result on Google: https://github.com/luca-piccioni/OpenGL.Net

Comment: @Longoon12000 OpenGL is not a library in that sense, it is a specification [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few options out there. In general, OpenGL is portable across systems and cards, but there are always implementation quirks. Are you following a tutorial, or are trying to port something from Windows or .NET Full Framework to Linux and/or .NET Core?

If you are trying to games related stuff (as many people doing graphics are), then you might want to check out [MonoGame](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame), as it will give you graphics access and a good starting point for games. This project is derived from an old unmaintained Microsoft project called [XNA](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20914).

If you are going lower level, I'm sure there are countless libraries. There is a C/C++ library called  [Simple Direct Media Layer (SDL)](https://www.libsdl.org/) which I'm sure has many C# wrappers,  [here's what I found on Nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SDL/). You can also just search "C# .NET SDL Simple Direct Media Layer Wrapper" and find something that looks good for your use case.

SDL is great to learn because it is widely used library that makes writing portable graphics-related code easier, but still is quite minimal.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question was how to use OpenGL (in .NET Core) and not how to use a API for creating windows ore an game engine.

Comment: Which naturally depends on what libraries he's using, and what I suspect is a critical part of the problem he's having.

Comment: SDL is a DirectMedia Layer but doesn't provide any OpenGL API.

Comment: "SDL has the ability to create and use OpenGL contexts on several platforms(Linux/X11, Win32, BeOS, MacOS Classic/Toolbox, Mac OS X, FreeBSD/X11 and Solaris/X11). This allows you to use SDL's audio, event handling, threads and times in your OpenGL applications (a function often performed by GLUT)." - From the SDL docs

His OpenGL code should work anywhere, but getting the other setup working can be problematic.

Comment: But it doesn't provide the API  and that is what the questioner is asking for. He is searching for something like [OpenTK](https://opentk.net/) or
[sharpgl](https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpgl)  for .NET core

Comment: @n234: Regardless what you suspect to be the underlying issue, your answer does not lead the OP any closer to achieving his/her objective.

Comment: GLFW is far superior to SDL ... hands down.